Running shell script with crontab but output is not displayed in the terminal
An enthusiastic Linux learner asks this:

The abarco user is trying to run a simple shell script with crontab. Here the script:
myjob.sh:
#!/bin/bash
echo Hello i am running $0 at $(date)


The script has x-permissions
[abarco@myLinuxVM log]$ ls -lrt /tmp 


-rwxrwxr-x. 1 abarco abarco 52 Apr  8 14:29 myjob.sh


The crontab is supposed to run it at a determined time but no output is displayed in the terminal
[abarco@myLinuxVM log]$ crontab -l
38 14 * * * /tmp/myjob.sh



The question is:
Why is no output displayed in the terminal?
echo is supposed to print output in the terminal.

thanks @steeldriver, now i understand that cron jobs run at the background and are not displayed in my terminal. Your suggestion worked. Now what is interesting to me is this syntax:
[abarco@myLinuxVM tmp]$ crontab -l
17 15 * * * /tmp/myjob.sh > /tmp/runningscript.txt 2>&1
My understanding was that 2>&1 meant : 2 is std error being sent to the output terminal,  what confuses me is the part where the output of the script is considered error , do you mind explaining this?

It's not being "sent" but rather "redirected as/copied to" i.e. output is no longer identified as as originating from stderr but rather considered as coming from the standard output stream at this point ... if that's what you're asking about.

that is exactly what i meant, the std error(2) word/concept gave me wrong idea that there was sth wrong with the outcome of my script and that was precisely what was being sent to my runningscript.txt file.   Thanks a lot  for taking your time-
